# using sed keep part of the pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I'm using sed to delete part of the string but the regular expression used in sed is a little bit different from other programming languages. 
Here is the sentence to be tackled:

```
"{\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 little} G{\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 }EDFW, {\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 one two}i{\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 </span><span>} {\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 </span><span>}= {\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 </span><span>}G{\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 </span><span>}TOTW, {\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 </span><span>}i{\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024 </span>}"
```

I want to delete string like this `{\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024}` (pattern like ({\sth)* (keep)}) and  keep whatever followed after the space e.g. `<span>`

I tried this:

```
sed 's/{[^\\.* (.*)}]*}/\1/g'
```

the output should looks like:

`little GEDFW, one twoi</span><span> </span><span>=</span><span>G</span><span>TOTW, </span><span>i</span>`

but it seems "." includes space and the way I try to catch the minimum match didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon — and how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) sooner.  Please show exactly the output you want from the input.   Is the input a single line?  You say you want to match a character sequence (`{\cs6\f1\cf6\lang1024}`) that doesn't appear in your input (there are spaces and span tags between 1024 and the close brace); that makes it hard for us to guess what you're really after.  The `\cs6\f1\lang1024` sequence appears multiple times in the input; should it be processed once or each time it appears, or what?

Answer (score -1):

It is easier to remove the parts you do not want:

```
sed 's/{\\cs6\\f1\\cf6\\lang1024 *//g; s/}//g' input_file
```